# DAX Using Countrows and Filter to compare value in the same table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm freshly new to DAX & PowerBI, I tried to create a measure column that will count the number of child of each parent has.

The table is something like this (please understand this table structure might be not ideal, but I can't change the existing).

[image: Table]

What I expect is to create a new column that will count how many "child" that the "parent" has based on "Parent ID". Like this.

[image: Expected column]

I've tried using this formula but it returns error

```
Childcount = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Table, 
        FILTER(
            Table, 
            Table[Parent ID] <> BLANK()
        ) = Table[ID]
    )
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done. Just a quick note, there are two types of calculations you canmake in Power BI: measure and calculated column. I Guess you're in nedd of a calculated column so here's a solution using calculated columns.

First create a calculated column like this:

```
Parent ID = 
var idcol = [id]
var result = 
IF( 
    [Type] = "Child",
    CALCULATE( 
        MAX('Data'[ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Data'), 
            'Data'[Type] = "Parent" && 'Data'[ID] < idcol
        )
    ),
    BLANK()
)

return
result
```

Then you can create a second calculated column like this:

```
Childcount = 
var idcol = [ID]

return
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(Data[Parent ID]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Data),
        'Data'[Parent ID] = idcol
    )
)+0
```

Since you're new to Power BI/Dax I would highly recomend you check youtube and sqlbi for free introductory videos. Before you understand the concept of how calculations are performed in Power BI you're gonna have a tough time. But it's worth the time investment!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, this works perfectly. I basically need the second calculated column. Yap, agree, it's a bit confusing with the calculation & formula logic, thank you for your suggestion!